# Inserting large CSV file into Postgres using Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying to read a large CSV file and insert the file in Postgres using Node.js. What should be the best way to read and insert records in batches. Below is my code. I am trying to divide the records into batches of 1000. Struggling in which point should I be initializing the Postgres db and inserting.

If i run this code i am reading the csv as below. I am stuck how i can insert the values in batches.

```
Id,City__c
12345678,"Test 1223"
87654321,"Test 8888"
Read entirefile.
```

Js file

```
const fs = require( 'fs' ),
    es = require( 'event-stream' ),
    parse = require( "csv-parse" ),
    iconv = require( 'iconv-lite' );
const pgp = require( 'pg-promise' )( {
    capSQL: true
} );

const client = {
    connectionString: 'postgres://ubbmdkfcbfgkfn:89fbe24d9cf50335a0667757d318797cebda6f1d6c2904560a8431aeb9f0040d@ec2-54-75-248-49.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/ddbimqs3ehvtug',
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}

class CSVReader {
    constructor ( filename, batchSize, columns ) {
        this.reader = fs.createReadStream( filename ).pipe( iconv.decodeStream( 'utf8' ) )
        this.batchSize = batchSize || 1000
        this.lineNumber = 0
        this.data = []
        this.parseOptions = { delimiter: ',', columns: true, escape: '/', relax: true }
    }

    read( callback ) {
        this.reader
            .pipe( es.split() )
            .pipe( es.mapSync( line => {
                ++this.lineNumber

                parse( line, this.parseOptions, ( err, d ) => {
                    console.log( line )
                } )

                if ( this.lineNumber % this.batchSize === 0 )
                {
                    callback( this.data )
                }
            } )
                .on( 'error', function () {
                    console.log( 'Error while reading file.' )
                } )
                .on( 'end', function () {
                    console.log( 'Read entirefile.' )
                } ) )
    }

    continue() {
        this.data = []
        this.reader.resume()
    }
}


let intializeDBAndInsert = () => {
    const db = pgp( client );
    let sco;

    db.connect()
        .then( obj => {
            sco = obj;
            let reader = new CSVReader( 'F:/data.csv' )
            reader.read( () => reader.continue() )
        } )
        .then( data => {
            // success
            console.log( data )
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            // error
            console.log( error )
        } )
        .finally( () => {
            // release the connection, if it was successful:
            if ( sco )
            {
                sco.done();
            }
        } );

}

intializeDBAndInsert();
```

Comment: You can use the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) query. This is fast and efficient, but only for postgres.

Comment: Your code is a mess, and so is the question. You pull in and use two database drivers - `pg` and `pg-promise` at the same time. And your question about when to initialize the database is quite off point here.

Comment: Is there anyway u can help me..

Comment: You need to narrow down your question first, and clean up the code, so people can understand what exact issue you are having.

Comment: cleaned the code and i have mentioned the issue .